# Create a custom lightdm greeter

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, g++

I am creating a custom LightDM-Greeter using [docs](http://people.ubuntu.com/%7Erobert-ancell/lightdm/reference/ch01.html) provided by conical. The problem is that these docs do not specify the linking procedure of the lightdm library.

I am running `Arch Linux x86_64`. On querying using `pkg-config --cflags --libs lightdm` I get no results, `Package lightdm was not found in the pkg-config search path` to be specific.

So, do I need to build the src and then statically link to the objects, or is there a way to dynamically link to something like `lightdm.so`.

I installed lightdm using `pacman -S lightdm`.

Comment: as you were creating your own greeter, I would like to ask you if you know how I could add my second laptop-battery to the greeter I'm using now? I'm using slick-greeter. My goal is to clone it and add support for my second battery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to link it (to the display manager program), once it has become a shared executable (which is something you need to check) it is completely linked.

To link it as a shared executable you need to add the `-shared` parameter to the compiler (this makes it a shared executable) and include all the `.o` files on it at link time.  You can also include options to avoid adding the C runtime (but I think that's implicit in the `--shared` option)  As it is loaded at run time with **dlopen(3)**, you should also specify *Position Independent Code*, with option `-fPIC` at compilation on each of the `.o` files that will be linked together.  That last option produces object code that can be loaded at any position, as that is needed only for shared executables, it must be specified at compilation time.  So, for example, if you have `a.o`, `b.o` as object files for your greeter, a compilation as:

```
cc -c -fPIC a.c b.c                 # compilation of a.c and b.c
cc --shared a.o b.o -o greeter.so   # linking to greeter.so
```

should be enough.

Greeters are normally loaded as shared libraries for the XDM display manager in use, to allow you to switch between them without the overburden of having all of then in memory when only one is used at all.  You normally specify somewhere in the configuration where and how the shared object si to be found, and then it is loaded and executed by use of the **dlopen(3)** functions. (see documentation on **xdm(8)** for that) and it loads it and executes the functions.  You'll notice because the login widget shows up at login.

For testing purposes, I should use **xdm(8)** as the x display manager, as it allows to specify how and where the xdisplay greeter is to be found. (and it is very well documented for programmers)  Then try to use it on the display manager of your preference. (possibly with some variations)  Most probably, they are all compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `pkg-config --libs --cflags liblightdm-gobject-1`?

Comment: Nope. `Package liblightdm-gobject was not found in the pkg-config search path`